# Extract number from certain strings in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a text like below

```
AB-MFG 49UN STEEL
GH-NH, 345UN IRON
M787 UH, 77 UNITS GREY
G7-YUT 365 UNITS WHITE
```

and i want to extract the numbers before string `UN` and `UNITS`

```
+------------------------+-----+
| AB-MFG 49UN STEEL      | 49  |
+------------------------+-----+
| GH-NH, 345UN IRON      | 345 |
+------------------------+-----+
| M787 UH, 77 UNITS GREY | 77  |
+------------------------+-----+
| G7-YUT 365 UNITS WHITE | 365 |
+------------------------+-----+
```

Currently I'm using belong query. I have to write a case statement to cover both cases. Are there any alternate efficient solution for this?

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(LEFT(desc, CHARINDEX('UN ', desc))), 2, 1000), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(REVERSE(LEFT(desc, CHARINDEX('UN ', desc))), 2, 1000))))
FROM MYTABLE
```

Comment: What do you mean by "too big"? Its OK for the query to have a few characters.

Comment: That's right.I will remove that statement. I'm looking for alternate solution that covers both cases and efficient than this. @DaleK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PATINDEX` with `CROSS APPLY`.
*I see a pattern that your required number is always appearing after the space and before your keyword*. If that is the case, you can use the below code.

```
SELECT DESC, 
       CASE WHEN UN.I !=0 THEN SUBSTRING(DESC,NUM.I+1,UN.I-NUM.I-1)
            WHEN UNITS.I !=0 THEN SUBSTRING(DESC,NUM.I+1,UNITS.I-NUM.I-1)
            ELSE ''
       END AS REQUIRED_NUM
FROM MYTABLE
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%UN %', DESC)))UN(I)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('% UNITS%',DESC)))UNITS(I)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('% [0-9]%', DESC)))NUM(I)
```

Please note that `desc` is a keyword in sql server. You should avoid using that for a column name.

Answer (score 0):

you could use an IIF in stead of the case

```
declare @mytable table (value varchar(100))

insert into @mytable values('AB-MFG 49UN STEEL'), 
                           ('GH-NH, 345UN IRON'),
                           ('M787 UH, 77 UNITS GREY'),
                           ('G7-YUT 365 UNITS WHITE')

select IIF(CharIndex('un ', value) = 0, CharIndex('units', value), CharIndex('un ', value))
from   @mytable
```

this will return the position of the `UN`  and the `UNITS`
From there you can do all the rest again.

Its not much better, but its an alternative for the case at least

**EDIT**

the full query would look like this than

```
declare @mytable table (value varchar(100))

insert into @mytable values('AB-MFG 49UN STEEL'), 
                           ('GH-NH, 345UN IRON'),
                           ('M787 UH, 77 UNITS GREY'),
                           ('G7-YUT 365 UNITS WHITE')

select reverse(left(ltrim(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(LEFT(value, t.PosValue)), 2, 1000)), charindex(' ', ltrim(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(LEFT(value, t.PosValue)), 2, 1000)))))
from   ( select value,
                IIF(CharIndex('un ', value) = 0, CharIndex('units', value), CharIndex('un ', value)) as PosValue
         from   @mytable
       ) t
```

and the result is this

```
COLUMN1
49 
345 
77 
365
```